# ref.current.contains is not a function in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

I made a dropdown toggle in React. My dropdown working perfectly fine. But when I try to close the dropdown while clicking outside of the dropdown menu. It shows error. I used ref to find the container element.
Sample code

```
class Search extends React.Component{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
        this.state={
            notificationStatus:false,
            isFocus:false


        }
        this.container=React.createRef()
    }
    toggleNotification=()=>
    {
        this.setState({notificationStatus:!this.state.notificationStatus});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
      }
      handleClickOutside = event => {
          if(this.container.current)
          {
        if (this.container.current && !this.container.current.contains(event.target)) {
          this.setState({
            notificationStatus: false,
          });
        }
    }
      };
    render()
    {
        const {isFocus,notificationStatus}=this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                    <div className="col-md-1 col-sm-1 bell-container flex all-center relative">
                        <img src={bell} onClick={this.toggleNotification} alt="bell icon" />
                    </div>
                {
                    notificationStatus ?  <NotificationList ref={this.container} /> : null
                    
                }
                
            </div>

            
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error that it shows?

Comment: It shows container.current.contains is not a function

Comment: have you console.logged out what `container` and `container.current` are?

Comment: Yes, I do. container.current shows the NotificationList component while the event.target shows the DOM element which I clicked.

Comment: Had the same issue "Uncaught TypeError: ref.current.contains is not a function" the reason is I placed `ref={ref}` on React component instead of on div surrounding this component.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding a **ref on NotificationList** component will not give you the reference of the DOM element rendered in it, you need to pass down the ref to the `div` within `NotificationList`

```
<NotificationList innerRef={this.container} />
```

and in NotificationList

```
class NotificationList extends React.Component {
   render() {
      <div ref={this.props.innerRef}>{/* */}</div>
   }
}
```

P.S. a short solution is to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.container.current)` but its not longer recommended to use in React

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your nested if at

> handleClickOutside

method, just make it correct as follow

```
      handleClickOutside = event => {
    if (this.container.current && !this.container.current.contains(event.target))               {
      this.setState({
        notificationStatus: false,
      });
    }
}
```